# Logic and technique JavaScript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good day, I have a list of "names" that fill the labels of some inputs DYNAMICALLY bone the number of "names" in the list never it will be the same, I'm filling the label with ng-repeat and I put inside an input number that also appears, the problem is that when you save that data not meeting the way link the name and the amount entered in the input.

```
 <div ng-repeat="Producto in productos" ng-if="Producto.Propio === true">
                <label class="item item-input">
                <div class="input-label">
                    {{Producto.DescCorta}}
                </div>
                <input class="center" ng-model="Producto.Cantidad" ng-required="true" type="number" placeholder="cantidad de piezas">
            </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you post some more code? Difficult to solve only looking at the view. But as I can make out: You're dynamically generating input boxes? And when you save, the values don't come over correct? ps. probably a good practice to code in English, since everyone can actually read the descriptive variables ;)

Comment: First thing I notice is that you generate the same input box every product... They all have the same ngModel and no unique identifiers. You'll never know what input belongs to what product when you save.

Comment: My question is, how can i link the "name"(dynamic label) and the input number. The ng-model doesnt exist yet, Producto(my array), and DescCorta the value of the name. How can i give them a unique identifier if the names of the list and the amount of inputs are never the same?, thanks in advice and sorry for my english.

Comment: This is what you need then: http://www.shanidkv.com/blog/angularjs-adding-form-fields-dynamically